# ReactQueryCacheProvider vs ReactQueryConfigProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

What is the difference between the **ReactQueryCacheProvider** and **ReactQueryConfigProvider** in react-query? I think the CacheProvider is a must due to it is the provider in order to use the context of react-query for the application. ConfigProvider seems to be an option in order to provide default configuration for the **useQuery**, the thing is that the configuration can be passed down to the CacheProvider.

Someone can explain why to use the ConfigProvider besides the CacheProvider, and when should be it used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about `ReactQueryCacheProvider` - it is needed for react-query to pass the queryCache to you via react context so that you can do `useQueryCache`. On the `ReactQueryCacheProvider`, you can also define default options for all your queries.

`ReactQueryConfigProvider` is an optional provider component and can be used to define defaults for all instances of useQuery within it's sub-tree. So you can override defaults only for parts of your application.

Please note that this is all for v2. `react-query v3`, which was released recently, only has a `QueryClientProvider` instead of `ReactQueryCacheProvider`, and `ReactQueryConfigProvider` doesn't exist at all anymore. You can read about this in the Migrating to v3 guide here: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/migrating-to-react-query-3#reactqueryconfigprovider-and-reactquerycacheprovider-have-both-been-replaced-by-queryclientprovider